# Bootstrap row layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a form that will appear in a modal window and I have the form looking exactly what I want.  Here's my HTML (only showing the first row because I believe the right solution will apply to all my rows)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <form action="#" method="post">            
                <fieldset>
                    <legend style="width: 80%">Base Information</legend>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-sm-5'>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for="user_firstname">First name</label>
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="user_firstname" name="user[firstname]" required="true" size="30" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-sm-5'>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for="user_lastname">Last name</label>
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="user_lastname" name="user[lastname]" required="true" size="30" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm currently viewing this using Chrome and when I horizontally resize the browser window to less than 760 pixels, all the form elements are stacked on top of each other.

[image: Here is what it looks like.]

As you can see there's a lot of spacing to the right I'm trying to get rid of.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can eliminate the padding on the right?

Comment: `col-xs` instead of `col-sm` would help with the breakpoint issue. You seem to have empty space on the right because you specified two columns of empty space `<div class="col-sm-2">&nbsp;</div>`

Comment: The spacing to the right is due to the fact that the form is contained within a `col-sm-8` div and within that there's a `col-sm-2` with nothing in it.

Comment: @j08691 - That certainly helped.  Can you put your response in a seperate reply so I can give you the credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`col-xs` instead of `col-sm` would help with the [breakpoint](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) issue. You also seem to have empty space on the right because you specified two columns of empty space `<div class="col-sm-2">&nbsp;</div>`. [Bootstrap's grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) is based uon 12 columns per row, so the two column spanning div would be occuping space.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap suggests 12 columns. Your layout uses only 9 of them:

```
<div class="col-sm-1">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
...
</div>
```

You can use `col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1` instead of `col-sm-8`, `<div class="col-sm-1">&nbsp;</div>` and `<div class="col-sm-2">&nbsp;</div>` ([offsetting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
      <form action="#" method="post">            
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Base Information</legend>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="user_firstname">First name</label>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="user_firstname" name="user[firstname]" required="true" size="30" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="user_lastname">Last name</label>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="user_lastname" name="user[lastname]" required="true" size="30" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```